# Grails GORM query on two associations

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I need to query on a domain that has two associated objects.

```
class UserVideo {
    User user
    Video video
}
class User {
    String name
}
class Video {
    String title
}
```

I need to find all the UserVideos that belong to a given user and where the video.title is like a string. For example "Find all the UserVideos that belong to user 'Fred' and the Video.title is like '%Potter%'."
No matter what I've tried, nothing works.

As requested, here is the code I have for my action:

```
    def list(Integer max, String title) {
    def userName = springSecurityService?.principal?.username
    def user = User.findByUsername(userName)
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    def results
    if (title) {
        def c = UserVideo.createCriteria()
        results = c.list {
            eq("user", user)
            video {
                ilike("title", "%${title}%")
            }
        }
    } else {
        results = UserVideo.findAllByUser(user, params)
    }
    def userVideos = results.collect({ UserVideo uv ->
        [uId: uv.user?.id, vId: uv.video?.id, number: uv.number, title: uv.video?.title,
                format: uv.video?.format?.name, rating: uv.video?.rating?.name, genres: uv.video?.genreNames]
    })
    [userVideos: userVideos, total: UserVideo.count()]
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
URI
/movies/userVideo/list
Class
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException
Message
Column "VIDEO_ALIA1_.TITLE" not found; SQL statement: select this_.user_id as user1_2_0_, this_.video_id as video2_2_0_, this_.number as number2_0_ from user_video this_ where this_.user_id=? and (lower(video_alia1_.title) like ?) [42122-170]
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
def c = UserVideo.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
  eq("user", User.findByName("Fred"))
  video {
    ilike("title", "%Potter%")
  }
}
```

Update - Try HQL

```
UserVideo.executeQuery("""
  Select uv
  From UserVideo as uv join uv.video v join uv.user u
  where lower(v.title) like lower(:title)
  and u = :user
""", [user: user, title: "%${title}%"])
```

Comment: If you have my sql, you can use rlike function as well. That way you can match the tithle anywhere, start, middle or end

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error:                                     URI
/movies/userVideo/list
Class
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException
Message
Column "VIDEO_ALIA1_.TITLE" not found; SQL statement: select this_.user_id as user1_2_0_, this_.video_id as video2_2_0_, this_.number as number2_0_ from user_video this_ where this_.user_id=? and (lower(video_alia1_.title) like ?) [42122-170]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `executeQuery` on domain class.

**Sample:**

```
def newUser = new User(name: "Fred")
def video = new Video(title: "Harry Potter")
[newUser, video]*.save(flush: true)

def userVideo = new UserVideo(user: newUser, video: video)
userVideo.save(flush: true)

def result = UserVideo.executeQuery(
                  "Select distinct uv from UserVideo uv " + 
                  "where uv.user.name = :userName " + 
                  "and uv.video.title like :title",
                  [userName : "Fred", title: "%Potter%"],
                  [max: 10, offset: 10]) //EDIT
//Pagination included. (max: 10, offset: 10) can also be part of the params maps like
//[userName : "Fred", title: "%Potter%", max: 10, offset: 10]

assert "Fred has the movie Harry Potter" == 
             "${result[0].user.name} has the movie ${result[0].video.title}"
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution seems to work. However, I also need to pass in paging information (ie offset=10?max=10). When I do a "findAllBy" call, I simply pass in the params hash and it does the right thing. For example: UserVideo.findAllByUser(user, params). Is there a similar call with executeQuery?

Comment: Yes you can pass pagination parameters in `executeQuery` as well. See my edit.

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much! Now for a bonus question... Since I am doing paging, how can I determine what the total set of matches is? For example if I use "%to%" as my title value, I need to know that there are 200 matches where the title contains "to." However, since I'm passing in a max of 10, I only get 10 results back. I could make two separate calls (one with max, and the other without), but this seems terribly inefficient.

Comment: I have not tested it yet but have you tried getting `count(*)` as well in `executeQuery`. My guess, you would get the total count of the match plus `max` rows will be 10.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here. How would I include the count(*) in the executeQuery?

Comment: You can visit here for more details about getting `count` in HQL. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html